# Make CSS triangle repeat vertically ( sawtooth pattern )

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I have navigation like:

```
------
|    |
|    |
|    |
|    |
|    |
------
```

And I would like:

```
------
|    |>
|    |>
|    |>
|    |>
|    |>
------
```

I decided it would be easiest to do this as separate divs, the second only concerned about repeating a pattern down the length of the nav.

I looked for help here but most articles I find are about horizontally repeating triangles.  I like this solution http://jsfiddle.net/QeZG6/ ,
but I have no idea how to convert the code to stack right-facing triangles vertically.

Help pertaining to the answer and how to do linear gradients is appreciated

Comment: Did you try `repeat-y` instead mate. That seems to solve it. I feel very odd to post this as an answer because I have basically done nothing here. [Sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QeZG6/38/).

Comment: repeat-y doesn't make the triangles face right, however

Comment: Depends if you are viewing the white or the black triangles :) [This](http://jsfiddle.net/QeZG6/40/) might be closer to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for something closer to

```
.pattern {
       background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, black 17px, transparent 18px), linear-gradient(45deg, black 17px, transparent 18px);
       background-size: 50px 50px;
       background-repeat: repeat-y;
       height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: This looks nice.  How'd you figure 135 and 45 degrees?

Comment: I just made the height and width into a square (50px by 50px) and then it is much easier to use more basic angles to get the desired result.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like

```css
html {
    background-image: linear-gradient(319deg, transparent 30px,black 31px),
                      linear-gradient(39deg, black 16px, transparent 17px);
    background-size: 23px 40px;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you know, if all you need is to rotate that, then you could technically, rotate that. and you will keep the smooth edges this way...

```css
.pattern {
    background-image: linear-gradient(320deg, black 15px, transparent 18px), linear-gradient(40deg, black 16px, transparent 18px);
    background-size: 54px 23px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 26px;
    width:500px;
    transform:rotateZ(90deg) translate(200px,250px);
}
```

```html
<div class="pattern"></div>
```

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen css rotate yet, interesting

Comment: @Kiwizoom there are plenty of 2d and 3d css transforms, its pretty cool and very handy

Answer (score -1):

If you would like them to appear on the right then you will need to use `background-position` and set the repeat to y.

http://jsfiddle.net/QeZG6/39/

Comment: Repeat-y is simple enough, but I need the triangles to face right.

Comment: I would recommend using an actual image of the triangle you require as you'll have some compatibility issues with linear-gradient.

Comment: That's a valid concern, I thought about it.  But I got slightly determined to learn linear-gradients, for better or worse