# horizontal line of repeating CSS triangles

Tags: css, background, border

I am trying to achieve the following using CSS (just the white triangled horizontal line, not the grey background).

[image]

I am trying to apply it to a psuedo element like so, but I know I am missing something, or not doing it correctly.

```
&:after {
  content: '';
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #fff 0%, #fff 50%, #a48d01 50%, #a48d01 100%);
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: add `inset:0` to after

Comment: related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28350138/make-css-triangle-repeat-vertically-sawtooth-pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `conic-gradient()`. Adjust the variable `s` to control the size and the `80px` to control the distance between triangles

```css
.box {
  --s: 25px;
  height:200px;
  background:
   conic-gradient(from -135deg at var(--s) 50%,red 90deg,#0000 0) center/80px calc(2*var(--s)) repeat-x
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.gradient-bg{
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 50px, transparent 0px, #a48d01 50px, #a48d01 100px), linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 0px, transparent 50px, red 50px, red 100px);
  background-size: 40px;
  background-position: 0 30px;
}
```

```html
<p class="gradient-bg"></p>
```

Maybe this can give you some idea. you need to use two gradients.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).